# applicationWillTerminate and applicationShouldTerminate don't get run on macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplication, nsapplication-delegate

I want to do some stuff when an application terminates, so I added `applicationShouldTerminate:` and `applicationWillTerminate` methods to my AppDelegate.  However, when I run my app from XCode and then press `⌘Q`, neither method gets called.

Now I'm testing by both logging and calling `printf`, and I don't see any output anywhere when I quit my app.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428522-applicationwillterminate?language=objc) seems to indicate that this should work.  Google hasn't yielded anything useful, and searching GitHub for example code mostly returns applications that watch other applications getting terminated.

Why aren't `applicationShouldTerminate:` and `applicationWillTerminate` getting called?

Here's those method implementations in my app delegate:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    printf("printf applicationShouldTerminate");
    NSLog(@"NSLog applicationShouldTerminate");
    return NSTerminateNow;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    printf("printf applicationWillTerminate");
    NSLog(@"NSLog applicationWillTerminate");
}
```

(I've also tested by making a brand-new project in Xcode, which you can find at https://github.com/noahlt/TestTerminator).

Comment: Works for me - how are you creating the project, and what action is the quit menu item connected to?

Comment: @red_menace I just tested by creating a brand-new Xcode project.  Still doesn't work.  You can see my complete project here: https://github.com/noahlt/TestTerminator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this by editing `Info.plist` and setting `Application can be killed immediately when user is shutting down or logging out` to `NO`.

[image: screenshot of edited Info.plist]

It's pretty weird to me that Xcode autogenerates the method stub for `applicationWillTerminate` but by default it doesn't work due to this `Info.plist` key.  For future reference, I am running Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500).

(Found this answer on the [Apple Developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126418#396322).)